# Having issues with my Tailwindcss project

Tags: css, layout, display, web-frontend

Writing the code for this tailwind project and when I was through with the hero section, I got to the next section and some how my coded is getting crammed up and underneath the previous section when displayed on in mobile view[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjYnf.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqNkB.png).

the images provided are the site in mobile and desktop display mode. ive been trying to get this issue fixed but to no avail!

p.s: I'm actually new to frontend web dev

I've tried using gpt and bard to maybe fix the problem. I've written the entire cod but still nothing.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="scroll-smooth">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Checkmate Landing Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/css/style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-z3gLpd7yknf1YoNbCzqRKc4qyor8gaKU1qmn+CShxbuBusANI9QpRohGBreCFkKxLhei6S9CQXFEbbKuqLg0DA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
  </head>
  <body class="px-2 sm:px-0 font-Poppins">
    <header class="container">
      <!-- HEADER -->
      <nav class="flex items-center justify-between py-4 md:py-12">
        <div class="-ml-8">
          <a href="#"
            ><img src="img/checkoutmate-logo-4.png" alt="" class="w-[250px]"
          /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="justify-end">
          <ul class="hidden gap-12 text-xs uppercase md:flex">
            <li class="self-center hover-bg">
              <a href="#features">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="self-center hover-bg"><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
            <li class="self-center hover-bg"><a href="#contact">Conatct</a></li>

            <div
              class="px-6 py-2 text-white rounded-md bg-checkmate-engin-orange hover:">
              <button type="button">Login</button>
            </div>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-20 sm:hidden">
          <i class="text-2xl fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
      <!-- HERO -->
      <section class="relative max-h-screen mb-20">
        <div
          class="container flex flex-col-reverse items-center justify-center md:flex-row">
          <!-- HERO CONTENT -->
          <div class="flex-1 text-center sm:text-left">
            <h1 class="px-2 mb-6 text-3xl sm:px-0 md:text-5xl">
              CheckoutMate: The Smart Way to Shop and Pay
            </h1>
            <p class="text-xl text-gray-500">
              CheckoutMate is a browser extension that makes shopping and paying
              online easier, faster, and more secure. <br />

              It allows you to compare prices from multiple retailers with a
              single click, find and apply coupons automatically, save your
              shipping and billing information for faster checkout, and pay
              securely with your preferred payment method.
            </p>

            <div class="flex flex-row justify-center mt-4 sm:justify-start">
              <button class="btn">Get for Browser</button>
              <button class="mx-6 btn-light">Get for Mobile</button>
            </div>
            <!-- button need to be adjusted for small screen -->
          </div>

          <!-- HERO-IMAGE -->
          <div class="self-end mb-12 animate-bounce">
            <img
              class="object-cover w-[500px] overflow-hidden"
              src="img/checkmate-hero.png"
              alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ROUNDED REC -->
        <div
          class="absolute right-0 hidden bg-orange-500 rounded-l-full top-[300px] w-1/2 h-80 md:block overflow-hidden -z-10"></div>
      </section>

      <!-- FEATURES -->
      <section
        id="features"
        class="py-20 mt-20 bg-bookmark-white lg:mt-60 dark:bg-slate-800">
        <div class="mx-auto">
          <h2 class="mt-20 text-2xl">Features</h2>
        </div>
      </section>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
The same is true for all other HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

You've set a max height of `100vh` on the hero section. The main culprit of the overflowing content is the hero image. It isn't shrinking on smaller screens, so it's making the height of the hero content taller than `100vh`. If the screen is small enough, the content ends up overflowing. I would suggest changing the image size on smaller screens. You can also try changing the text size, but I would focus on the image. For example, you can do something like this in your `HERO-IMAGE` section:

```html
<!-- HERO-IMAGE -->
<div class="mb-12 animate-bounce self-center md:self-end">
  <img class="w-[150px] sm:w-[300px] md:w-[500px] overflow-hidden object-cover" src="img/checkmate-hero.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Read more about [Responsive Design](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design#overview) from the Tailwind docs if you want to learn more.